# How to define from google app script on which tab it was triggered?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a spreadsheet with few tabs in it and i want to trigger my `onEdit` script only if one tab was edited. 
How can i from script define on which tab it is triggered?

Comment: You can't. You'll `return` your function, if the  edited range was not your sheet

Comment: Use the event object to execute the appropriate code for a given sheet by writing code guards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Scripts onEdit trigger for specific sheets in a spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465608/google-apps-scripts-onedit-trigger-for-specific-sheets-in-a-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event object to find the edited range, then use the range to find the sheet, then check that the sheet's name matches the one you want;

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();

    if (sheetName === 'yourSheetNameHere') {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Why has this been down voted? It's a valid answer. Help me write better answers by telling me what's wrong.

Comment: it was voted down not by me. I marked this answer as correct, thanks!